# Should the accounts Umair and Umair be merged?

Tags: discussion

I have just reviewed this [post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/67570/3-5-inch-elecrow-lcd-not-working-on-retropie/67663#67663).

It seems the question was posted by a user Umair and their question was answered. I then assume they forgot their account details, created a new account and posted an "answer" saying their question has been answered.

Could this user be contacted and asked if they would like their accounts merged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've left a note there; this is something only S.E. staff can, [but they do have a mechanism](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Of course, if you forgot the password and used a dud email because you didn't think it would matter who you logged in as later, then you are probably out of luck.